# Simplify procedure to group labels

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a big data set with the al nuclides and I would like to group them by most likely decay. I have produced the following code, where the data frame is a sample of my big one and I would like to know if this can be simplified in any way. According to H. Wickham, one should never copy-and-paste more than twice, and I ended up copy-and-pasting four times, but any attempt I have done either involves loops, or a much longer code.

```
# Prepring data base sample
Sym <- c("Ba", "Bi", "Po", "Rn", "Ca", "Am", "Pm", "Ir", "Cd", "Na")
A <- c(142, 207, 199, 227, 34, 239, 146, 203, 120, 26)
Z <- c(56, 83, 84, 86, 20, 95, 61, 77, 48, 11)
N <- c(86, 124, 115, 141, 14, 144, 85, 126, 72, 15)
dcy <- c("B-", "EC+B+", "B-", "A", "B-", " ", "B-", "B-", "EC+B+", "B-")
decays <- data.frame(symbol = Sym, a = A, z = Z, n = N, decay = as.factor(dcy))
rm(Sym, A, Z, N, dcy)

# Implementation of the name change

decays_type <- levels(decays$decay)
decays_type

# Filters
beta_p_filter <- decays$decay %in% decays_type[grep("^.?B\\+.?", decays_type)]
beta_m_filter <- decays$decay %in% decays_type[grep("^.?B-.?", decays_type)]
alpha_filter <- decays$decay %in% decays_type[grep("A", decays_type)]
epsilon_filter <- decays$decay %in% decays_type[grep("^.?E.?", decays_type)]
other_filter <- !(alpha_filter | beta_p_filter | beta_m_filter | epsilon_filter)

# Grouping the isotopes according to the most likely decay
decays$label[beta_p_filter] <- "beta plus"
decays$label[beta_m_filter] <- "beta minus"
decays$label[alpha_filter] <- "alpha"
decays$label[epsilon_filter] <- "electronic capture"
decays$label[other_filter] <- "other"

decays
```

The example is self-contained and works, but the filtering and grouping like this looks unelegant, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do the same.

Thank you for any help or hint you can give me.

**Please note:** the `grep` regular expressions are a bit more generic than what is needed in the sampled data set, but there are more types of decays in the big data set, e.g. `2B-`, `2EC`, `P` , `N` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to have few unique identifiers, regex might be overkill and `match`ng a `dict`ionary might be easier.

```
dict <- read.table(text="
  decay               label
   'B-'         'beta minus'
'EC+B+' 'electronic capture'
    'A'              'alpha'
", header=TRUE)

decays$label <- dict$label[match(decays$decay, dict$decay)]
decays <- transform(decays, label=replace(label, is.na(label), 'others')) 
decays
#          symbol   a  z   n              decay
# 1      Ba 142 56  86    B-         beta minus
# 2      Bi 207 83 124 EC+B+ electronic capture
# 3      Po 199 84 115    B-         beta minus
# 4      Rn 227 86 141     A              alpha
# 5      Ca  34 20  14    B-         beta minus
# 6      Am 239 95 144                   others
# 7      Pm 146 61  85    B-         beta minus
# 8      Ir 203 77 126    B-         beta minus
# 9      Cd 120 48  72 EC+B+ electronic capture
# 10     Na  26 11  15    B-         beta minus
```

Or use `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex`.

```
repl <- c("beta plus", "beta minus", "alpha", "electronic capture")
decays$label <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
  decays$decay,
  pattern=c("^.?B\\+.?", "^.?B-.?", "A", "^.?E.?.*"),
  replacement=repl,
  vectorize_all=FALSE
)
decays$label[!decays$label %in% repl] <- 'others'
decays
#    symbol   a  z   n decay              label
# 1      Ba 142 56  86    B-         beta minus
# 2      Bi 207 83 124 EC+B+ electronic capture
# 3      Po 199 84 115    B-         beta minus
# 4      Rn 227 86 141     A              alpha
# 5      Ca  34 20  14    B-         beta minus
# 6      Am 239 95 144                   others
# 7      Pm 146 61  85    B-         beta minus
# 8      Ir 203 77 126    B-         beta minus
# 9      Cd 120 48  72 EC+B+ electronic capture
# 10     Na  26 11  15    B-         beta minus
```

---

*Data:*

```
decays <- structure(list(symbol = c("Ba", "Bi", "Po", "Rn", "Ca", "Am", 
"Pm", "Ir", "Cd", "Na"), a = c(142, 207, 199, 227, 34, 239, 146, 
203, 120, 26), z = c(56, 83, 84, 86, 20, 95, 61, 77, 48, 11), 
    n = c(86, 124, 115, 141, 14, 144, 85, 126, 72, 15), decay = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), levels = c(" ", "A", 
    "B-", "EC+B+"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice idea, but the overall identifiers are more than 20 in the complete data set, so typing them all would be quite challenging. I had to use the regex because there are also some slight variations, like sometimes there is an extra space between types, sometimes a comma, etc.

Comment: This is absolutely lovely, and it is easily generalisable to include other decays, such as `SF` if I decide to change the graph of nuclides. Thank you ever so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. If I may ask, why did you change the regex to `"^.?E.?.*"`? Was it wrong without the asterisk?

Comment: @Logos Welcome, happy to help! Yes, without the `.*` it just captures just the `"E" plus one character but not the rest, check [here](https://regex101.com/r/jVfwtb/1).